# how to give user input while build by ANT using docker or docker file

Tags: docker, build, ant

In build.xml i have put input  but when ant get called by dockerfile  at runtime it does not ask any input while build and it take all default values given in input (in build.xml) so how can i add input while build by ant using docker compose

Answer (score 0):

To give input while build using ant..

run the dockerfile by this command

```
docker build -t ant .
docker run -i -t ant
```

where,
  -i -t :- accept input from user while build.
  ant :- image name